# My config trying to find color management, how can I make it gone?

Tags: color-management, startup-file

This is my config from last workplace. My technical director write something into it and now blender trying to find color management. I don't want blender to write this titles. Raw/new blender don't write it. But I need my config. How can I make it?
+ I don't need Aces at all. I need standart srgb. I just want blender not try to find Aces on startup
[image]

Comment: It looks like your technical director has decided to use ACES with Blender for some really unfortunate reasons. You’ll need the ACES configuration your team is using.

Comment: I don't need Aces, I'm working home now in srgb. I need blender not searching ACES

Comment: Then mark the other question as the correct solution. In your Blender folder, you will see `release/datafiles/colormanagement`. Replace it with the default from Blender or another of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the color management folder within the previous install folder (C:\Program FIles\Blender Foundation\Blender XXX\datafiles) and copy it to the new install.